# IIS 10.0 HTTP Error 404.13

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

- Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

I am trying to upload an Video, But i am getting an error.

I did you this code in my web Config file

```
    <system.web>        
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
```

But the browser is showing error.

Is there any specific length for videos or this length supports video upload?

Comment: What is the size of the video you are trying to upload? There are two settings you may need to consider http://taimooradilbadshah.blogspot.com/2013/05/maxrequestlength-and.html

Comment: Some servers implement a maximum file size around 10Mb to 20Mb.  Is your maximum greater than actual file size?  I would add extra length to cover wrapper text the http adds to the actual file size.

Comment: Its an Mp4 file and the video length is around 40 MB.